# Can I move appsettings.json out of the app directory?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to put my appsettings.json file outside of the web folder so that I can avoid storing it in source control. How can I do this?

Comment: Keep it where it is and don't include it in source control?

Comment: So where would you get settings from at runtime?

Comment: ... web publish empties the folder upon publishing.

Comment: You need that file when you publish, you just don't need to put it in your source control.

Comment: Yes, but how do you publish that file without it being in source control?

Comment: If you're publishing locally, then if the `appsettings.json` file is in your project, whether or not it's in source control, it will be published along with everything else. However, doing automated builds and releases would definitely problematic, as there's not much of an opportunity to get the file to actually exist without some sort of custom scripting to create it.

Comment: I'm guessing there's a way of having Visual Studio Online fill in some place holders from its store of secret variables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't like relative paths, it seems. But, this works...

```cs
public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            if (!hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                var parentDir = Directory.GetParent(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath);
                var path = string.Concat(parentDir.FullName, "\\config\\appsettings.json");

                config.AddJsonFile(path, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            }
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

So, it's another settings file on top of the sources added by default.

Comment: seems like relative paths inside project root are fine but navigating outside project root via a relative path is not working :( weird

Answer (score 3):

If you truly don't want it in your source control, the best advice is to keep it where it is and simply add it to the ignores for your source control, so it's never committed, as @PmanAce suggested.

However, I personally think files like `appsettings.json` *should* be committed. They essentially serve to document the configuration necessary for the application. Without that as a guide, how is any one supposed to know what should go in the `appsettings.json` they'll have to create because it won't be included in the pull from your source control?

That said, there is the issue of storing sensitive data to think about. However, there's other ways around this. You can use other means of configuration such as environment variables and/or user secrets to override anything in `appsettings.json`. Therefore, for things like connection strings, provide a placeholder in your `appsettings.json` so it's self-documenting that a value for that needs to be provided, but for your own personal use, utilize user secrets and/or environment variables to override that value with something real. That way, you can freely and safely commit `appsettings.json`, fully documenting what settings are necessary for your application, without worry that personal or secret information is being included with it.

Comment: Yes, I'm leaving appsettings.json in the project and it's being deployed - for documentation and non-sensitive settings. And, yes, I could leave sensitive data encrypted in Visual Studio Online but for now, the simplest thing to do is hide an overriding version elsewhere in the file system, as I'm doing.

Comment: Actually, have you tried configuration via user secrets (which is a local thing, by the way, not part of VSTS)? It's super simple and works flawless for development.

Comment: It's only for development. I think the ideal is to have sensitive app settings encrypted when deployed. Traditional web.config enables this. I'm not sure if MVC Core supports it.

Comment: Well as with pretty much everything in ASP.NET Core, it supports what you add to it via middleware. None of user secrets, environment variables or appsettings.json support encryption. However, there's additional providers such as Azure Key Vault, that do. If something you need doesn't exist, you can always create custom middleware, as well. I believe there actually is now a Web.config custom configuration provider, now in .NET Core 2.0, but I haven't used it and can't attest to how well it works or whether or not encryption is supported.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, even with the old web.config way, it was never a fantastic idea to include your connection strings and such in your source control, even encrypted. The problem was that you really didn't have much of a choice. ASP.NET Core does provide you a choice, and given that you can now abstract these secrets entirely from your application, you *should*.

Comment: web.config files can reference another file. https://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/5261

Answer (score 0):

For `.Net Core 6` i had to set root folder before i could change app configuration as posted by @ian-warburton, because if not it throws the error:

> System.NotSupportedException: The web root changed from
> "C:\app\wwwroot" to "C:\app". Changing the host configuration using
> WebApplicationBuilder.WebHost is not supported. Use
> WebApplication.CreateBuilder(WebApplicationOptions) instead.

The folder were the app will run is the current working directory.
It is valid for running from visual studio and docker container with the standard Dockerfile, at least.

```
const string ConfigFolder = "./Config"; //can be relative or fullpath
IConfiguration configuration = null; //so it can be used on other configuration functions bellow

//create the WebApplication on the current folder
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args =args,
     WebRootPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "wwwroot")), //point where if serving static files from default location. Works for my case. May need some adjustments in other cases.

});

//load config file, build it, give it to WebApplication and keep the config variable for further use.
builder.WebHost.ConfigureAppConfiguration(
    (hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var path = Path.Combine( ConfigFolder, "appsettings.json");

            config.AddJsonFile(path, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            configuration = config.Build();
        });
```